# Gtk and Python: Problem using set_label and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk

I have a thread that runs the function uidReader() which reads NFC cards using read_uid(). When I have the UID from the card I want to write it in the label. Then, when I press the Clear button I want to remove the UID form the label and run a new thread to be able to read a new card. The problem is that some times (I can not identify any pattern, it seems random) the UID gets stuck in the label and I can not change the value pressing the Clear button.

```
import time

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, GObject, Gdk

from rfid import Rfid

def uidReader():
    uid = rf.read_uid()
    print(uid)
    LogWin.label.set_text("uid: " + uid)

class LoginWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Login")
        Gtk.Window.set_default_size(self, 600, 200)

        self.box = Gtk.VBox(spacing=0)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.label = Gtk.Label(label="Please, login with your university card")
        self.label.width_chars = 100

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Clear")
        self.button.set_margin_start(20)
        self.button.set_margin_top(20)
        self.button.set_margin_end(20)
        self.button.set_margin_bottom(20)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.clearButton)

        self.box.add(self.label)
        self.box.add(self.button)

    def clearButton(self, button):
        self.label.set_text("Please, login with your university card")
        global uid_thread
        if uid_thread.is_alive() is False:
            uid_thread = threading.Thread(target=uidReader, daemon=True)
            uid_thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    uid = False

    rf = Rfid()
    uid_thread = threading.Thread(target=uidReader, daemon=True)
    uid_thread.start()

    LogWin = LoginWindow()
    LogWin.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    LogWin.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html, you should only use GTK+ and GDK from the thread gtk_init() and gtk_main() were called on.

Wrap the call to GTK+ in a `GLib.idle_add`, so replace

```
LogWin.label.set_text("uid: " + uid)
```

with

```
# from functools import partial
GLib.idle_add(partial(LogWin.label.set_text, "uid: " + uid))
```

Comment: Nearly you got to return False from an idle_add callback if you don't want it to repeat.

Comment: Why are you using partial()? I think that this should work: `GLib.idle_add(LogWin.label.set_text, "uid: " + uid)`

Comment: @DanD. returning None works just fine, returning False makes it more verbose...